# Does Liferay support case insensitive LDAP user login?

Tags: authentication, liferay

I am trying to login into liferay portal as LDAP user. screen names are by default case sensitive for internal validation.

But for external validation, i.e, an LDAP user with name say TestUser and if i try to login as testuser, the login is failed in the portal, but the console says that login is successful.

How to add case insensitivity to liferay for LDAP users also..i.e, for external validation?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a CustomAuthenticator by implemeting `com.liferay.portal.security.auth.Authenticator` to override the default behavior. Then you could use `auth.pipeline.pre=com.auth.YourCustomAuth`